# What If I Need Conditional/Overriding (synchronized) .yml Config Install With a Custom Module?

Tags: 8, installation, configuration

With D8, the appropriate method for adding fields during install with a custom module is with the config system and `.yml` files in a `config/install` directory.

I have a module for user theming I like to use for new D8 site installs, it adds hooks, templates, fields.

With a minimal install, this module provides the field and storage config for the `user.user.user_picture` field, as well as the `entity_form_display` and `entity_view_display` for compact and token view modes for the user.

I also include some custom fields such as `first_name` and `last_name`.

Obviously, with a standard install, this module will get the errors that the `user.user.user_picture` config already exists among others.

I would really prefer that the config overwrites the display config for the view modes, but would take them just being ignored on install if it already exists.

Is there a method following the Drupal config system to get conditional, or overriding, (synchronized) config during install? Or do I need to use the features module?

Is there a definitive approach for this?

Comment: What you might be able to do is add a hook_install() in your .module and then load the relevant config entity that you want to change e.g. $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('entity_form_display');
  $view_display = $storage->load('user.user.default'); then you can alter the settings within that and then $view_display->save(); to save. As a way to get round the error

Comment: A worthwhile approach, wondering if I shouldn't also do `hook_schema()` and add any fields to the user table via `\Drupal::database()->insert`... Unless I am missing a method to call config `.yml` files in `hook_install()`?